# Get Customers using Postman Magento ver. 1.9.4.2

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have Magento ver. 1.9.4.2, When I try to retrieve customers using Postman, it does not show anything. I am using this end point https://myhost/rest/V1/customers
What could be the problem? I tried https://myhost/api/rest/customers

Answer (score 0):

What response are you getting? Are you making a GET request? The response status code/messaging should give you a clear indication of the issue. It's likely that you may need to authenticate your requests https://devdocs-openmage.org/guides/m1x//api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html